# tool to refactor html attributes to html5

Tags: html, css, asp.net, attributes, refactoring

I'm doing a lot of asp.net webforms development on an older codebase.  Is there a tool or technique anyone can recommend for refactoring HTML 4 level attributes to CSS style?  For instance:

```
    <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
```

becomes

```
    <td style='vertical-align:top; white-space: nowrap;">
```

Bonus points for CSS consolidation ;)  It appears Coderush offers a "refactor html attributes to css" refactoring but it appears Resharper does not.

For now, I am doing a clever bunch of search/replace with regexes but its very tedious.  Some sort of slapchop that could just be invoked would be awesome :)

Comment: `<td class="top nowrap">` and use stylesheets

Comment: Thanks, yes, that was the second part about css consolidation, but it still requires wading through all the different attributes that may be in use, this was just a sample.  Most of these style attributes have been migrated to CSS and are no longer valid in HTML5.

Comment: How many do you have? You could scrape them and extract all attributes, sort them into styles and grep the codebase

Comment: Thanks that is a good idea if it was static HTML.  Unfortunately these are mixed server side pages so scraping would not edit the source which has a lot of embedded server side tags.